# How do I earn the "Sleeping Giant" Achievement?

Tags: powerstar-golf

In Powerstar Golf, there is an achievement called, "Sleeping Giant".

The description says:

> Earn XP when not playing the game

How can I earn XP when not playing the game?  Is it in a booster pack ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find it.  When you play rounds in Free Play, Rival mode and Stroke play in local multiplayer, your best round gets posted to Rival mode.   In Rival mode (which you select from the start menu), you can challenge to play against other players rounds [on your friends list or hit `X` on the Xbox to Show Other Players].  If you beat your opponents score, you will earn XP.  If you don't beat their score, they will earn XP.

So to earn the achievement, you will have to post a Stroke score in Free Play, Rival mode, or in local multiplayer.  Then someone will have to challenge you and lose **while you are not playing Powerstar Golf**.  After they lose, you will earn XP and that achievement when you come back online.

I was able to test this with a friend: *He scored -12 in rival mode, went offline, and then I played against his -12 score.  I ended up losing and he unlocked the achievement when he logged back in.*

[image]